# KEY do Maps não está funcionando

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Recentemente tive que formatar o pc... E fiz um backup dos meus projetos...
Quando reinstalei o Android Studios e abri o meu projeto percebi que o mapa não está aparecendo!!!

Mas todo o resto da integração com o Firebase está funcionando...
estou desconfiando que está acontecendo alguma incompatibilidade com essa Key...
Como eu faço para utilizar novamente essa KEY que eu tinha habilitado no meu projeto?

Comment: Qual KEY? Geralemente você consegue fazer download das chaves no proprio Google Console.

Comment: google_maps_key.... Eu vou ter que ficar gerando uma nova key toda vez que eu for alterar o projeto??? :(

Comment: Eu tô ligado que a chave é atrelada ao Package name e o SHA-1 certificate... É possível que a chave tenha mudado??? Como eu faço pra restaurar o antigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As keys das APIs do google console, em tempo de desenvolvimento, são atreladas a um keystore de debug que é gerada no momento de instalação das ferramentas de desenvolvimento android. Com a nova instalação, te foi gerado uma keystore diferente da primeira instalação. Sendo assim, é necessario que repita o processo de geração do token passando novamente a assinatura SHA1 (agora do novo keystore) no console google.

Obs: O console consegue receber mais de um SHA1 ao mesmo tempo, isso possibilita que mais de um developer possa trabalhar no mesmo app ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Muito obrigado Messias!!!!!!!!!!